# Show that there exists non-zero countable ordinal $\delta$ such that $\omega\delta=\delta$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I am stuck on the following problem that says:

> Show that there exists non-zero countable ordinal $\delta$ such that $\omega\delta=\delta$

*My Attempt*:

Previously I solved a question similar to this one:

> Show that there exists non-zero countable ordinal $\delta$ such that $\omega+\delta=\delta$

where I chose $\delta=\omega^2$, and because of the ordinal arithmetic, $\omega$ on the left is cancelled due to the higher order of $\omega^2$

But, here I couldn't find any idea,

Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: $w \neq \omega$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* In your previous argument,

\begin{align*}
\omega + \omega^2 &= \omega + (\omega +\omega+\dots)\\
& = \omega+\omega+\dots\\
&= \omega^2
\end{align*}

Now try to turn $+$ into $\cdot$ into in this argument. What should you replace $\omega^2$ with?

*Better hint:* (in response to your comment)

If you replace $+$ with $\cdot$ in the middle equation above, you get: $$\omega\cdot(\omega\cdot\omega\cdot\dots) = \omega\cdot\omega\cdot\dots$$

Now can you see a more compact way of writing the answer?

Comment: I still can't get the idea, if we replace $\delta$ with $\omega^2$ don't we get $\omega^3$?

Comment: @Galymbek If you don't understand the answers, you shouldn't have accepted one yet - this indicates the question is settled.

Comment: I'm a newbie here, I didn't understand fully how the website works, sorry.

Comment: @Galymbek I've edited my answer with a more explicit hint.

Comment: Yes! Now I see, choose $\omega^\omega$. Thank you)

Answer (score 2):

The two problems are essentially the same intuitively.

In the one you've solved, the mental picture should be $$(\color{red}{\omega})+(\color{green}{\omega+\omega+\omega+\omega+...})=(\color{blue}{\omega+\omega+\omega+\omega+\omega+...}),$$ and the green and blue blocks are the same.

In the new problem, the only difference is that "$+$" has been replaced with "$\cdot$" - so what's the analogous mental picture (and can you turn that into a precise answer/proof)?

Comment: @Galymbek yes, so $\omega^2$ doesn't work. What's the *analogue* of $\omega^2$ here? (Remember, the key feature of $\omega^2$ for the first problem is that it's $\omega+\omega+\omega+...$ - now what changes when we move to the second problem?)

Comment: Thank you! I've got the idea)